# fgets() randomly changes between returning NULL and returning the correct value

Tags: c, file, null, fgets

While calling this function that I made to get lines out of a file `fe`, sometimes the function works and keeps working for a while until it randomly decides it doesn't want to work anymore and `fgets()` starting returning `NULL` (I am not allowed to use getline as an alternative). 
I tried remaking the function from scratch but it still doesn't want to work. I am a thousand percent sure that my file exists and that it is being loaded.

Excuse the rookie code please, second month using C.

```
int getEtudiants(FILE *fe, int *num, char nom[100][30],char pre[100][30],char sec[100][10]) {
    FILE *p;
    p = fe;
    fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET);
    //char temp[5] = {0};
    char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 75);
    int i = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    int ch;
    int n = 0;

    while((ch = getc(p)) != EOF) {
        if(ch == '\n') lines++;
    }
    fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET);
    //printf("found %d students\n", lines);
    char *lineBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 75);

    for(i = 0; i < lines; i++){                   
        fgets(lineBuffer, 76, p); 
        strncpy(temp, lineBuffer, 5);
        num[i] = atoi(temp);
        strncpy(nom[i], lineBuffer + 5, 30);
        trimStr(nom[i]);
        strncpy(pre[i], lineBuffer + 35, 30);
        trimStr(pre[i]);
        strncpy(sec[i], lineBuffer + 65,10);
        trimStr(sec[i]);
        //printf("num: %d,%s %s section: %s\n", num[i], nom[i], pre[i], sec[i]);
        fseek(p, 2, SEEK_CUR);
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: How do you know `fgets` is returning NULL if you never check the return value?  Also, what's the point of `fseek(p, 2, SEEK_CUR);`?

Comment: Niggle: you allocated 75 bytes `char *lineBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 75);` but `fgets(lineBuffer, 76, p);` can exceed that.

Comment: Additionally, you `malloc()` but do not `free()`, so you have a memory leak.  But the `malloc` is altogether unnecessary -- simply declare `temp` and `lineBuffer` as ordinary arrays of `char` (which then do not need to be freed).

Comment: What, by the way, is the point of the `fseek(p, 2, SEEK_CUR)` inside the loop?  That's pretty suspicious.

Comment: I did check the return of fgets by using printf to print out the lineBuffer, it printed (null) in most cases. The lines im reading are 75 characters long but for some reason fgets with 76 worked flawlessly along with the fseek(p,2,SEEK_CUR) which helped go to the next line by stepping over the \n (which for some reason, fseek counted as 2). The function worked perfectly until randomly, it decided to stop functioning entirely.

Comment: "I did check the return of fgets by using printf to print out the lineBuffer" --> that is **not** checking the return value of `fgets()`.  `fgets()` is a function with a return value - check that.  e.g. `for(i = 0; i < lines && (fgets(lineBuffer, 75, p) != NULL); i++) {`

Comment: @georgedefented -- note that when `fgets()` returns a null pointer, the contents indicated by `lineBuffer` may remain unchanged, or alternatively may become indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

chux correctly noted that "using printf to print out the lineBuffer" *is **not** checking the return value of `fgets()`.* And we can infer more: "it printed (null) in most cases" means that `lineBuffer` was NULL, and

```
char *lineBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 75)
```

indicates that `malloc()` returned NULL, i. e. it ran out of memory or the memory management was corrupted - both is conceivable.